# Heroku, CarrierWave, MiniMagick: random tmp file missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, imagemagick, image-manipulation, carrierwave

in my RoR project I am using CarrierWave + MiniMagick and deployed to Heroku for production.

I have this problem in production that sometimes the tmp file is missing for image processing. I get this error:

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/mini_magick20130319-2-3wq6l6.jpg`

I have other XUploader classes that works but this particular one have two image processes. Initially I had two separate process for this:

```
  process :resizer
  def resizer
    resize_to_fit(model.jrac_image_width, model.jrac_image_height)
  end

  process :cropper
  def cropper
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.crop("442x190+#{model.jrac_crop_x}+#{model.jrac_crop_y}")
      img
    end
  end
```

but it said I was having error on `:cropper` saying the tmp file doesn't exist. I tried to change the code to this, hopefully it will only work on it once:

```
  process :resize_and_crop
  def resize_and_crop
    manipulate! do |img|
      img.resize("#{model.jrac_image_width}x#{model.jrac_image_height}") # resize_to_fit
      img.crop("442x190+#{model.jrac_crop_x}+#{model.jrac_crop_y}") # cropper
      img
    end
  end
```

but unfortunately, still experiencing the same errors.

Does anyone have any idea where the problem is? I don't know if it's with Heroku or CarrierWave or ImageMagick?

**Edit**

I also have this code on my `Uploader` class

```
  def cache_dir
    "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
```

as for this [document](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3a-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku).

Answer (score 0):

heroku will empty the tmp from time to time, usually, we use s3 or other cloud storage to store the processed version. You may refer to https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave and 
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-Make-Carrierwave-work-on-Heroku

They have detailed walkthrough on using carrierwave in heroku
I have tried that before and it works

Comment: Oh yes sorry. I do have this in my `Uploader` class: `def cache_dir; "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"; end`